# ASANA API display all tasks in PHP script

Tags: php, asana-api

I am using a simple php script which generates a task's name (it is quite long, that's why I build a generator for generating it).
Right now I need to copy generated name to ASANA, while I am creating a new task but I know that using ASANA API it can be integrated with my generator (when I click on GENERATE button the project's name is generated and a new ASANA task has been created with the generated name).

I created in my dashboard a Personal access token.
I downloaded this library https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class and filled up file `examples/task-creation.php` (all 3 fields with capital letters are correct filled):

```
<?php
require_once('../asana.php');

// See class comments and Asana API for full info
$asana = new Asana(array('personalAccessToken' => 'MY PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN')); // Create a personal access token in Asana or use OAuth

$workspaceId = 'MY WORKSPACE ID'; // The workspace where we want to create our task, take a look at getWorkspaces() method.

// First we create the task
$asana->createTask(array(
    'workspace' => $workspaceId, // Workspace ID
    'name'      => 'Hello World!', // Name of task
    'assignee'  => 'HERE MY EMAIL' // Assign task to...
));


// As Asana API documentation says, when a task is created, 201 response code is sent back so...
if ($asana->hasError()) {
    echo 'Error while trying to connect to Asana, response code: ' . $asana->responseCode;
    return;
}

$result = $asana->getData();

if (isset($result->id)) {
    echo $result->id; // Here we have the id of the task that have been created
}

?>
```

After running the script from my `localhost` directory I get following error:

```
Error while trying to connect to Asana, response code: 0
```

Any help regarding this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: I moved the file to a online host and it works! I'm stupid. Thank your very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move your file to an online host instead of localhost. It should work.